# NSFetchedResultsController: how does it know which objects to call its delegate for?

Tags: core-data

Anybody care to speculate about the internal workings of NSFetchedResultsController?

Specifically: how does it know which objects to call its delegate methods for? If I were to implement NSFRC, I'd do it this way: 1) register for all the notifications from the managed context, and 2) when I get a notification, check the type of the object against the type of the entity of the fetch request in the NSFRC, and check whether the predicate (if it exists) in the NSFRC returns true for that object, and if both are true, then call the delegate's ...didChangeObject... method.

Seems clunky though somehow, especially with that type-check (use isKindOf?). Just asking because I need to implement something similar in that respect to NSFRC.

Comment: +1 Awesome question, was wondering as well but haven't had the time to look into it (moved over to the Mac for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The managed object context broadcast a series of notifications and the user info dictionary of the notification contains the managed objects that were inserted, deleted, or updated.

E.g.

> NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
>
> Posted when values of properties of
>   objects contained in a managed object
>   context are changed. The notification
>   is posted during
>   processPendingChanges, after the
>   changes have been processed, but
>   before it is safe to call save: again
>   (if you try, you will generate an
>   infinite loop).
>
> The notification object is the managed
>   object context. The userInfo
>   dictionary contains the following
>   keys: NSInsertedObjectsKey,
>   NSUpdatedObjectsKey, and
>   NSDeletedObjectsKey.

The FRC then just checks the entity of the returned object across it's own entity and if it matches sends its delegate messages.

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote: so that 'just checks the entity' bit would involve type-checking the object (can it be just a pointer comparison of the object.entity == thefetchrequest.entity), and then checking if the predicate, if it exists, matches the object. Right? Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It does not type-check the object because a large percentage of the time, it will be a generic NSManagedObject instance that has been configured to model a specific entity. You could have dozens of entities all modeled by the same NSManagedObject class. Instead, it checks the NSManagedObject.entity value which returns a NSEntityDescription object. But otherwise, yes, I believe so.